# Set the properties of UserControl through other View or ViewModel

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, prism

I have a UserControl with two RadioButtons and a textbox and have a corresponding ViewModel to this View.
My Question is can this control be placed in some other Page and the properties i.e Radiobuttons must be disabled in few Views and enabled in some others
How do i expose these properties or set it from other Page
 I want UserControl To be a Provider View for other pages

Comment: DependencyProperty may be a Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `bool DependencyPropertiy` for each view:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRadioButtonEnabledProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsRadioButtonEnabled", typeof(bool), 
    typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));

public bool IsRadioButtonEnabled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsRadioButtonEnabledProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsRadioButtonEnabledProperty, value); }
}
```

And use it inside the `UserControl` like this:

```
<RadioButton IsEnabled="{Binding IsRadioButtonEnabled, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type Views:YourUserControl}}}" ... />
```

Then you can bind to this `bool` property from outside of the `UserControl` and set whether the controls are enabled or not:

```
<YourUserControl IsRadioButtonEnabled={Binding IsRadioButtonEnabled} ... />
```

Then in your view model:

```
public bool IsRadioButtonEnabled { get; set; }
```

Then to disable the controls:

```
IsRadioButtonEnabled = false;
```